# how to read hive conf variables in UDF initialize method

Tags: hive, hive-udf

I am trying to read a hive conf variable in initialize method, but not works, any suggestion plz?

My UDF Class:

```
public class MyUDF extends GenericUDTF {
    MapredContext _mapredContext;

    @Override
    public void configure(MapredContext mapredContext) {
      _mapredContext = mapredContext;
      super.configure(mapredContext);
    }

    @Override
    public StructObjectInspector initialize(ObjectInspector[] args) throws UDFArgumentException {
      Configuration conf = _mapredContext.getJobConf();
    // i am getting conf as null 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably its too late to answer this question, but for others below is the answer inside a `GenericUDF evaluate()` method:

```
@Override
public Object evaluate(DeferredObject[] args) throws HiveException {
    String myconf;
    SessionState ss = SessionState.get();
    if (ss != null) {
        HiveConf conf = ss.getConf();
        myconf= conf.get("my.hive.conf");
        System.out.println("sysout.myconf:"+ myconf);
    }
}
```

The code is tested on hive 1.2

You should also override `configure` method to support `MapReduce`

```
@Override
    public void configure(MapredContext context) {
        ...................
        ........................
        JobConf conf = context.getJobConf();
            if (conf != null) {
              String myhiveConf = conf.get("temp_var");
            }
        }
    }
```

To test the code:

1. Build UDF Jar
2. On hive CLI, execute the below commands:

   ```
   SET hive.root.logger=INFO,console;
   SET my.hive.conf=test;
   ADD JAR /path/to/the/udf/jar;
   CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION test_udf AS com.example.my.udf.class.qualified.classname';
   ```

Comment: mano, ele falou no initialize manooo.. vc mandou no evaluate! não ta dando assim

Answer (score -1):

I was also running into this issue with a custom UDTF. It seems that the configure() method is not called on the user defined function until the MapredContext.get() method returns a non-null result (see [UDTFOperator line 82 for example](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/ff67cdda1c538dc65087878eeba3e165cf3230f4/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/exec/UDTFOperator.java#L82)). MapredContext.get() likely returns a null result because the hive job has yet to spin up the mappers/reducers ([you can see that MapredContext.get() will return null up until the MapredContext.init() method has been called](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/exec/MapredContext.java#L50); the init() method takes boolean isMap as a param, so this method doesn't get called until MR/Tez runtime - [the comment associated with the GenericUDTF.configure() method confirms this](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/generic/GenericUDTF.java#L42)).

TLDR the UDF/UDTF initialize() method will be called during job setup, and the configure() will be called at MR runtime, hence the null result in your example code.